# Unable to acquire token silently

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I have cloned [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp) repo. Which uses adal-angular.js

Everything work as expected;except the token refreshing.
Indeed, if after 1 hour I do anything that issues an XHR to a protected resource then no more token being sent along with the request and I get stuck with a 401.
Shouldn’t be the token renewed silently by the hidden iframe? Or Am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add an end-point to get the token silently.

```
var endpoints = {
    'api/TodoList/': '00000000-0000-0000-000-000000000000',
};

adalProvider.init(
    {
        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
        tenant: 'foo.onmicrosoft.com',
        clientId: '00000000-5638-0000-000-000000000000',
        extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage', 
        endpoints: endpoints
    },
    $httpProvider
    );
```